# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" while using pthread_create

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads

So I've got a problem: when I trying to create the last thread it always says that core is dumped. Doesn't matter if I write to create 5 or 2 threads. Here is my code:
UPD: Now I can't do more than 3 threads and threads don't do functions that I want them to do(consume and produce)

UPD_2: Now I've go a message like that: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)

```
 #include<cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <condition_variable>

#define NUM_THREADS 4

using namespace std;

struct thread_data
{
   int  thread_id;
   int  repeat;
};


 class our_monitor{
    private:
        int buffer[100];
        mutex m;
        int n = 0, lo = 0, hi = 0;
        condition_variable in,out;
        unique_lock<mutex> lk;

    public:
        our_monitor():lk(m)
        {

        }
        void insert(int val, int repeat)
        {
            in.wait(lk, [&]{return n <= 100-repeat;});
            for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
            {
                buffer[hi] = val;
                hi = (hi + 1) % 100;        //ring buffer
                n = n +1;         //one more item in buffer
            }
            lk.unlock();
            out.notify_one();
        }

        int remove(int repeat)
        {
            out.wait(lk, [&]{return n >= repeat;});
            int val;
            for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
            {
                val = buffer[lo];
                lo = (lo + 1) % 100;
                n -= 1;
            }
            lk.unlock();
            in.notify_one();
            return val;
        }
};

our_monitor mon;

void* produce(void *threadarg)
{
    struct thread_data *my_data;
    my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;
    cout<<"IN produce after paramiters"<< my_data->repeat<<endl;
    int item;
    item = rand()%100 + 1;
    mon.insert(item, my_data->repeat);
    cout<< "Item: "<< item << " Was prodused by thread:"<< my_data->thread_id << endl;
}

void* consume(void *threadarg)
    {
        struct thread_data *my_data;
        my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;
        cout<<"IN consume after paramiters"<< my_data->repeat<<endl;
        int item;
        item = mon.remove(my_data->repeat);
        if(item) cout<< "Item: "<< item << " Was consumed by thread:"<< my_data->thread_id << endl;
    }

int main()
{
    our_monitor *mon = new our_monitor();
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    thread_data td[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        td[i].thread_id = i;
        td[i].repeat = rand()%5 + 1;
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << "main() : creating produce thread, " << i << endl;
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, produce, (void*) &td[i]);

            if (rc)
            {
                cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
                exit(-1);
            }
        } else
        {
            cout << "main() : creating consume thread, " << i << endl;
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, consume, (void *)&td[i]);

            if (rc)
            {
                cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[2], NULL);
    //pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

**UPD: Now I can't do more than 3 threads and threads don't do functions that I want them to do(consume and produce)**

**UPD_2: Now I've go a message like that: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)**

Comment: How do you know that it falls over in `main` rather than one of the thread procs?

Comment: Can you explain, to which functions does `produce`, and `consume` point?

Comment: I edit my question, there is full code

Comment: Use std::thread instead of pthreads.

Comment: It doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From cppref regarding std::condition_variable.wait(...)

> "Calling this function if lock.mutex() is not locked by the current
>   thread is undefined behavior."

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

Unfortunately, the program doesn't crash on line 47, but on line 55, where you unlock the lock that wasn't locked.

[image]

[image]

Lock the lock when you enter your functions. I've done a quick check of the rest of your logic, and I'm like 85% sure it's otherwise ok.

While I have you here, this is not strictly necessary, but it's good practice. std::lock_guard and std::unique_lock automatically lock the mutex when it enters scope and unlock it when it leaves scope. This helps simplify exception handling and weird function returns. I recommend you get rid of lk as a member variable and use it as a scoped local variable instead.

```
    void insert(int val, int repeat)
    {
        { // Scoped. Somewhat pedantic in this case, but it's always best to signal after the mutex is unlocked
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            in.wait(lk, [&]{return n <= 100-repeat;});
            for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
            {
                buffer[hi] = val;
                hi = (hi + 1) % 100;        //ring buffer
                n = n +1;         //one more item in buffer
            }
        }
        out.notify_one();
    }
```

Ok, now for the final issue. The cool thing about producer/consumer is that we could produce and consume at the same time. However, we just locked our functions so this is no longer possible. What you can do now is move your condition lock/wait/unlock/work/signal *inside* the for loop

in pseudocode:

```
// produce:
while (true)
{
    {
        unique_lock lk(m)
        wait(m, predicate)
    }
    produce 1
    signal
}
```

The is equivalent to using semaphores (which C++'11 stl doesn't have, but you can easily make your own as shown above.)

```
// produce:
semaphore in(100);
semaphore out(0);
while (true)
{
    in.down(1)  // Subtracts 1 from in.count. Blocks when in.count == 0 (meaning the buffer is full)
    produce 1
    out.up(1)   // Adds 1 to out.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `main` ends, `td` goes out of scope and ceases to exist. But you passed pointers into it to threads. You need to make sure `td` continues to exist as long as any threads might be using it.

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: @MaxPan One of the possible ways: joining with the threads at the end of `main`, so that threads had ended by the time `td` has gone out of scope.

Comment: One common pattern is to allocate a structure to pass data to a thread with `new`. Pass the thread the pointer you got from `new`. Then after the thread reads the data, it can `delete` it. That doesn't work if you need to pass data back from the thread though.